# Theme CSS have priority

Tags: css, wordpress

https://www.development-vip.co.uk/product/smirnoff-espresso-vodka-70cl/
(password: hide)

You will notice in the page source that my stylesheet (main-style) which I am loading at the highest priority is almost at the top in the head. Way above my themes style.

Why is my theme styling above it in the editor? Because its overriding the styles.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @j08691 : This has nothing to do with specifity: Look at the selectors in the screenshot: Settings in a `.col` rule are overwritten by settings in another other `.col` rule – both have the same specifity. It's a matter of the order in this case.

Comment: @Johannes Did I say that my link was an answer? No. If I had meant for it to answer the question, then I would've made it into a proper answer. I simply left the link on specificity as a reference for the OP. Thanks

Comment: @j08691 But there is no specifity issue, so what else is it for?

Answer (score 0):

The last loading css files will override previous stylings when they have same specificity (like simple class selectors in your example). You should put general (default) styles first and overrides below.

If there's a conflict with specificity you can make css rules more specific by prepending a selector. Below rule will go over the class selectors:

```
#main .col {
    /* styling here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the stylesheets are referenced/loaded in the header, which in this case (Wordpress) probably is part of the theme's `header.php` file. You can look in there to see if those two stylesheets are loaded in the wrong order and change it. However, you should probably create a child theme if you do this to avoid the edited `header.php` file to be overwritten when the theme is updated next time.